# Independent Brownian Motions and SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I have this question:
Suppose that $f$ is a function of $t$ and $Y(t)$, while $g$ is a function of $t$ and $Z(t)$, where
$dY (t) = c_1dB_1(t) + c_2dB_2(t)$, $dZ(t) = c_3dB_1(t) + c_3dB_2(t)$.

If $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$ are known constants and $B_1(t)$ and $B_2(t)$ are independent Brownian motions, determine the SDE for $d(fg)$.

I thought of writing out what $df$ and $dg$ would be, but I have no idea how to proceed because I'm not given what the original functions are. Can anyone help me get started on this problem?

Comment: Hint: apply Ito's lemma to the function $F(t,Y,Z)=f(t,Y)g(t,Z)\,.$

Comment: You don't need to know what the original functions are to write out the SDE: it will just be written in terms of their derivatives.